# Construction initialization VS Dependndncy injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am extremely new into dependency so could you explain does it possible to implement dependency injection without using IOC container such as Ninject  ,Unity ,Autofac etc. When these plugin is needed and when it can be done with out using these IOC container.

```
private readonly IModelFactory _modelFactory;
        private readonly IStatsService _service;

        protected BaseApiController( IModelFactory modelFactory, IStatsService statsService ) {
            _modelFactory = modelFactory;
            _service = statsService;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. The DI Containers that you mention make your life easier, but what they do basically boils down to this:

```
IModelFactory modelFactory = new MyModelFactory();
IStatsService statsService = new MyStatsService();

var myController = new SomeController(modelFactory, statsService);
```

DI Containers have some benefits to them: the heavy lifting is done for you (smart people have worked on it!), you specify in one place how you want your dependencies to be managed, and it's something that other developers will probably have seen already.

To integrate ASP.NET MVC with a DI Container, plugins already exist. For example, the Patterns & Practices team at Microsoft have made [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc), a small plugin that integrates Unity with the ASP.NET MVC infrastructure. When you do this, the MVC framework will automatically inject the dependant classes when it instantiates your controllers.